# I Have a table with column [Load date] and i want to add a column [Updated Date] ....in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a table with column `[Load date]` and I want to add a column `[Updated Date]` with Mon-Fri data same as `[Load Date]`, but Sun-Sat as Mon data of `[Load Date]`..... how can I do that in SQL Server?

Comment: What did You try so far?

Comment: What do you mean of Mon-Fri and Sun-San? is [Load date] is varchar containing "Sun-Sat"? or it is a datetime field type? You'd better to provide some sample data as well as what you already have tried.

Comment: Example:  LoadDate                       Update Date

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE table3
( 
 orderdate datetime
)


CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getupdateddate(@orderdate datetime)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
declare @updateddate datetime
  if datepart(weekday,@orderdate) in (1,2,3,4,5)
  set @updateddate=@orderdate;
  else 
  select top 1 @updateddate= orderdate from table3 
where datepart     (weekday,@orderdate) =2
  order by orderdate desc 
  return @updateddate

END

ALTER TABLE table3
ADD updateddate AS dbo.getupdateddate(orderdate)

select @@DATEFIRST--7  
insert into table3
(orderdate)
select getdate()

select * from table3  


  orderdate                    updateddate
2016-04-12 00:29:14.343   2016-04-12 00:29:14.343
```

Few points to note:
1.SET DATEFIRST specifies the first day of the week. The U.S. English default is 7, Sunday.
2.you might want to add is null if there are no days with Monday